# R ggplot bar group

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am learning ggplot2 and I want to plot a bar chart using the dataframe as is without converting it if possible.

Dataframe:

[image]

I want to plot it like this:

[image]

thanks,

Comment: look at `?geom_col` and the examples.

Comment: Please don't share data as pictures, we can't copy those into our session. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Axeman sorry I tried sharing it as a table but it wasn't really "copyable" so wouldn't have helped much... how should I share the data in future? thanks

Comment: @gmarais, there is a lot of useful advice here: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) Thanks!

Comment: @gmarais: You can transform your dataframe (and other objects) into code using dput()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made some artificial data similar to yous. I updated to include the labels:

```
df=data.frame(cd=seq(0,4),October=c(128,68,29,21,75),November=c(90,80,15,11,80),December=c(55,151,28,7,79))%>%
  melt(id.vars="cd",variable.name="Month")
df$cd<-as.factor(as.character(df$cd))
ggplot(df,aes(x=Month,y=value,fill=cd,label=value))+geom_col(position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(size = 4, position =position_dodge(1),vjust=-.5)
```

[image]

Off course you could change the grouping of your data, if for instance you would like x to represent cd and colors representing Month

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=cd,y=value,fill=Month,label=value))+geom_col(position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(size = 4, position =position_dodge(1),vjust=-.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So I have to `melt` my data in order to use ggplot as is? If you can perhaps start with that as a comment then I can accept the answer..

Comment: Hi gmarais, ggplot works a bit different than basic plotting in R (and excel). When you want to plot different variables (columns), instead of picking them one by one, you have to put your values in one column and use factors to goup them in other column(s). I find melt function does this work handy, but other methods might do the trick as well.

Comment: For an overview of ways to do this transformation, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).